# Trying to delete value in array, using unset. PHP

Tags: php, arrays, unset

Reading elements from `$file` to array, return value of `array[0]` then delete element and save array to file
**unset is not working, why ?**
here is code:
*list.txt - file(1kb) 10 lines.*

```
    function files($files)
    {

        $list = array();
        $list = file($file) or die('read error');

        print_r($list); //debug


        unset($list[0]);

        $f = fopen($file, 'w+');
        flock($f, LOCK_EX);
        foreach ($list as $string) {
            fwrite($f, $string);
        }
        print_r($list); // debug
        flock($f, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($f);
return $s = ($list[0]);
}
```

Comment: A good IDE would notice and warn you that you are writing code that will never execute. For example PHPStorm, and many others.

Comment: First of all you are not sending **`$file`** to your function and that's why your code isn't working in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return a value before your unset-statement:

```
function files()
{ 

    $list = array();
    $list = file($file) or die('read error');

    print_r($list); //debug

    return $s = ($list[0]);
    // Every statement after this line wouldn't be called, because you
    // already returned

    unset($list[0]);

}
```

Try

```
$result = $list[0];
// And at the end of your function
return $result;
```

Comment: No, it's definitly not the same. -- See comment of Shankar on your question why it still not works.

Comment: its working, thx!
also have 1 ore question if i use in function this construction, wil it be "good programming" ?

if ($a=='0')
{
return ($list[0]);
}else{
return ($list[1]);
}

Comment: Please don't edit your question like the new code was your original question. Only edit it to fix markup, add additional info etc. Now it doesn't make sense for someone reading the question for the first time.

Comment: Yes, that's good programming. However, because you `unset($list[0]);` a call to `return $list[0]` will give you an `Notice: Undefined offset: 0` and returs NULL